# Erro de execução JasperReport

Tags: java, ireport, jasper-reports

Estou com um problema com *JasperReport*, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para estudo, onde tenho um frontend que conecta com um db (sqlserver) para cadastros, consultas e relatórios. Na parte de relatório, quando vou executar, dá o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/digester/Digester  at
>   convenios.relatorios.TelaMovimentoConvenio.jButton1ActionPerformed(TelaMovimentoConvenio.java:103)
>     at
>   convenios.relatorios.TelaMovimentoConvenio.access$000(TelaMovimentoConvenio.java:26)
>     at
>   convenios.relatorios.TelaMovimentoConvenio$1.actionPerformed(TelaMovimentoConvenio.java:49)

O código que estou usando é:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package convenios.relatorios;

import convenios.modelo.Cliente;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;

/**
 *
 * @author Roberto
 */
public class TelaMovimentoConvenio extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TelaMovimentoConvenio
     */
    public TelaMovimentoConvenio() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(446, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(52, 52, 52))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        JasperPrint jasperPrint= null;
        MovimentoConvenioDataSource datasource = new MovimentoConvenioDataSource();


        for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++){

            Cliente cliente;
            cliente = new Cliente(i, "Nome "+i,"Endreco "+i);
            datasource.addAsistente(cliente);
           }
        try {
           inputStream = new FileInputStream ("src\\convenios\\relatorios\\movConvenio.jrxml");

       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao ler o relatório "+ex.getMessage());
        }

        try{
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, datasource);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "src\\convenios\\relatorios\\reporte01.pdf");

        }catch (JRException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao ler o relatório "+e.getMessage());
        }



    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Estou usando o netbeans 8.1, com as bibliotecas todas adicionadas no projeto.

*jasperreports-6.3.0, jasperreports-fonts-6.3.0, jasperreports-functions-6.3.0,     jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.0
commons-beanutils-1.9.2, commons-collections4-4.1, commons-digester3-3.2, commons-logging-1.2
sqljdbc4*

Não encontrei um exemplo fácil de uso do jasperReport novo 6.x com o japerstudio 6.x usando o netbean 8.1 só encontrei exemplos de uso com versões bem mais antigas 4.x e com o eclipse.

Consegui fazer funcionar fiz o download da versão 6.0.0 + joda-time-2.9.4 coloquei tudo que estava no lib nas bibliotecas, não tem mais erros. agora só da este warning

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

O relatório esta sendo gerado, mas não mostra o relatório :(

Tenho que adicionar realmente todas estas libs ao projeto, como sei quais libs devo acrescentar?

tudo funcionando agora adicionei  JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);

Mas somente na versão 6.0.0, onde pego as libs do jasperReport 6.3.0?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` ocorre quando uma das classes usadas não é localizada pela JVM. Pode ser um erro de importação no classpath ou você pode ter esquecido realmente de importar a lib da classe para seu classpath.

Comment: Olá obrigado, também acho que é um problema de importação de lib. mas esta confuso quais devo realmente importar. aqui http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements
fala uma coisa, mas em outros fóruns diz para importar também as que estão em:
 jasperreports-6.3.0-project\jasperreports-6.3.0\lib
só que não tem nada nesta pasta

Comment: Aparentemente o problema não são os impots e sim o classpath, veja se está carregando commons-digester.jar e também check commons-beanutils.jar, commons-collections.jar e commons-logging.jar.